# How can go into this <a> link using selenium driver? (google-chrome version 102.0.5005)

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

https://en.dict.naver.com/#/search?range=all&query=practice

[image of the link i want to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCJ9O.png)

[image of the html of the part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wejvf.png)

i want to click that word. That word is link so if i click that on the website then i will go to new page.

I tried to click that using it's xpath, like,

```
word_link=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchPage_entry"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a')
word_link.click()
```

but when i debugged, there's an error message;
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnZUh.png)

why the problem occurs?
And, how can i go into the link using selenium?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use other XPath and also add some wait

```
word_link= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//strong[@class='highlight'][normalize-space()='practice'])[1]"))

word_link.click()
```